# Please tell me how to create a hidden file on macOS

Tags: macos

Please tell me how to create a hidden file on macOS.

Please do not add the period to the beginning of the file name.

Comment: What are you expecting? A period in front is exactly how hidden files work on UNIX/Linux.

Comment: A period is **one** method, but it's not the only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Terminal…

`chflags hidden /path/to/file`

It will still show to `ls -a`

Comment: Thank you very much.
```
$ ls
```
It is visible by this.